# MS Access Message Bar not showing, but is enabled in Trust Center

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2016

I am having my query blocked, because Access is in "Disabled Mode." The only fix is to click on Options in the Message Bar. The Bar does not show up for me, I followed the steps to enable it in Trust Center settings, which I have done. After Access restart, System restart, everything, I still cannot get the Message Bar to appear. I tried adding the Show Message Bar in the Ribbon that just remains grayed out no matter what.

I am using Access 2016, on Windows 8 Professional, if this permissions-limited system has anything to do with it.

Has anybody run into this issue before, and can anyone recommend a fix? Thanks

Comment: Can you check in the registry if the place your' opening Access from/the file itself is a trusted location? `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\`

Comment: @Brad Yes, originally the only location listed in the Trusted Locations area was the folder with all the wizard files. I have another database going in Access (separate .accdb file) where I can run any type of query no problem. I originally had the same issue, but was able to get the Message Bar to appear but I can't remember how anymore! I added the current folder my database is stored in, saved the changes, restarted Access, but it still is in Disabled Mode.